# Handling just one file with Git

Tags: git, shell, database-backups

I want to save databases text backups to Git, to have changes and diff between versions. It will be a shell script:

1. Get database script to a file.
2. git stuff.

"git stuff" will add the file to Git repository with github remote add + commit + push maybe.

To Git gurus, what is the better option to handle this file? I think this script will be run in a database server that no necessary need all files in the repository. I saw some options here, like `git archive`, `git fetch` and `git sparse-checkout`, but I didn't really figure out the best option.

Comment: When you say "database", what amount of data are you talking about approximately?

Comment: Will be a MongoDB JS script (Json objects). Our databases are small, 2mb at most. I think file size will be no a problem. Thank you

Comment: Not relevant for your question, but anyone coming here based on the title might be interested in [Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: Keep in mind that git will add a new copy of the entire file, not just a diff, every time you push. Depending how often you push, your git repo may grow quite large.

Comment: @jwygralak67: Actually, that's not true. Internally, git stores blobs as differences ("delta compression") - especially efficient for text files.

Comment: @SirAthos So it does. I just re-read some documentation on that and realized that I had an incomplete understanding. Wikipedia says the following: Periodic explicit object packing
Git stores each newly created object as a separate file. Although individually compressed, this takes a great deal of space and is inefficient. This is solved by the use of packs that store a large number of objects in a single file (or network byte stream) called packfile, delta-compressed among themselves.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you have to tell Git to do that. It won't just happen automagically (although packing is done for network transfers for example).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best if you use a separate git repository just for this, especially since you don't want any other files on the database server.

With that said, all you need is `git clone` for the initial setup, then `add`, `commit` and `push` (assuming nobody else commits to that repository).

Comment: The Main idea is, have the "database backup" in the same project repository, I mean, the database for project A1, is in a folder "_databasebk" inside the project repository, you can access that file very quick, BUT, this is the main problem too, conflicts, merges, etc etc. Your option could be a good solution, maybe combine with modules or something like that?

Comment: Unlike svn, git encourages you to have multiple repositories, one per project. If you have the need, you can combine them with modules (not my personal favorite, due to the way they link to a fixed SHA), or have a mechanism which ties the db repo with your main one (a script, or a Makefile, or anything that works for your situation, to clone the db repo inside or side-by-side with the main repo, and to update it whenever needed).